# what's the property of a FeatureCollection in JSON

Tags: json, properties

I am new to JSON and I am trying to understand it. So I want to specify a rectangle. Therefor I am using a FeatureCollection in JSON. According to this [example](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#polygon) I have this:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature",
         "geometry": {
           "type": "Polygon",
           "coordinates": [
             [ [0.0, 0.0], [5.0, 0.0], [5.0, 5.0],
               [0.0, 5.0], [0.0, 0.0] ]
             ]
         },
         "properties": {
           "prop0": "value0",
           "prop1": {"this": "that"}
           }
         }
```

However, I am not sure what to set as a property?

I am assuming `prop0` could be something like a name, but what is `prop1`? Something like `type number` or `coordinates` again?

```
"properties": {
               "name": "null island",
               "prop1": {"type": "number"}
               }
```

Comment: We can't know this. Whoever produces the JSON data should have documentation what the data means. All we know is that you have a dictionary with two key-value pairs, the key "type" with a value "FeatureCollection", and the key "features" with an array value, with the first element being a dictionary and so on and so on.

Comment: so I can set it just like I want it? Do I even need two properties then? This example (http://www.macwright.org/2015/03/23/geojson-second-bite.html#polygons)  has only one property. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be referring to GeoJSON. From the documentation:

"A GeoJSON object with the type "Feature" is a feature object.

A feature object must have a member with the name "geometry". The value of the geometry member is a geometry object as defined above or a JSON null value.

A feature object must have a member with the name "properties". The value of the properties member is an object (any JSON object or a JSON null value).

If a feature has a commonly used identifier, that identifier should be included as a member of the feature object with the name "id". "

In JSON, values are arrays, objects (a collection of key-value pairs, often referred to as dictionaries, maps, hashes, associative arrays), strings, numbers, boolean values, and null values.

The "properties" key can have either "null" as its value, or an object (dictionary). Each value in the dictionary can be anything, including another dictionary.